# instanceof, subclasses and casting

Tags: java

if I have a class `myClass1` and a second class `myClass1Extended` that is an extension of the first class, I have this source code:

```
myClass1 c1 = something();   // line 1
myClass1Extended c1ex = somethingElse();   // line 2
if (c1ex instanceof myClass1) {    // line 3
    (myClass1)c1ex.doSomething();    // line 4
}
```

I have a few questions:

1. in Line 3, will the operator `instanceof` return true?
2. in line 4, supposing the first answer is yes, what will happen if doSomething() has not been overriden in myClass1Extended?
3. And what happens instead if doSomething() has been overriden?
4. in line 4, is (myClass1) necessary?

Thank you very much

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. Please try first, then ask later.

Comment: I thought it was a interesting question, and people gave me good answers, unfortunately I will delete it because there are others that think that I deserve a minus for it.

Answer (score 3):

Why don''t you try the code to see?

1. yes
2. it will call the one in the parent class
3. it will call the one in the child class
4. no.

Given:

```
class Parent
{
    public void foo() 
    {
        System.out.ptintln("parent::foo");
        bar();
    }

    public void bar()
    {
        System.out.println("parent::bar");
    }
}

class Child
    extends Parent
{
    public void foo() 
    {
        super.foo();
        System.out.ptintln("child::foo");
    }
}
```

You can use the Child class anywhere you use the Parent class, because all Children are types of Parents.

When the compiler looks at this code:

```
Parent p = new Child();
```

it verifies that the Child extends or implements the Parent.

When the compiler looks at this code:

```
p.foo();
```

it verifies that the type the `p` is declared as, `Parent`, has a `foo` method.

At runtime when the `p.foo()` line is executed the Virtual Machine looks at the type that `p` is actually pointing at, `Child`, and looks there for the `foo` method.  Assuming the `foo` method is found in `Child` it runs it, otherwise it looks at the `Parent` class for it.

In the Parent class when the `foo` method calls `bar` the compiler again looks to make sure that the `Parent` class has a `bar` method.  At runtime the VM again looks at the `Child` class to for the `bar` method, and since it does not it calls the one in the `Parent`.

If the methods don't exist in `Parent` then they have to exist the in the parent class of `Parent`, all the way up to `java.lang.Object`.

Comment: Because I think it was a part of knowledge missing here and because I actually already tested, but I wanted to be sure I did not have made some error. Finally, because it's a good way to undestand deeply the language. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question take this example here:

```
package test;

public class Parent
{
    public void printFoo()
    {
        System.out.println("foo");
    }

    public void printBar()
    {
        System.out.println("bar");
    }
}

package test;

public class Child extends Parent
{
    @Override
    public void printFoo()
    {
        System.out.println("myFoo");
    }
}

package test;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String ... args)
    {
        Parent test = new Child();
        Parent test2 = new Parent();

        print(test);
        print(test2);
    }

    public static void print(Parent parent)
    {
        if (parent instanceof Parent)
        {
            System.out.println(parent.getClass().getName()+" is Parent");
            parent.printFoo();
            parent.printBar();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see Child inherits from Parent and overrides printFoo() method. On printing those Parent objects you will get the following output:

```
test.Child is Parent
myFoo
bar
test.Parent is Parent
foo
bar
```

So to answer your questions:
1) yes
2) it will call the method of the parent class
3) it will invoke the overriden method - if this method contains a super-call then the parent's method will execute as well
4) No - if you specify f.e. `Parent o = new Child()` and implement a method in Child that is not present in Parent and you want to invoke the method of the child object, you will have to cast it back to Child `((Child)o).invokeYourMethod()`